# Read lines one by one asynchronously from stdin in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'm trying to use `readline` to read lines from `process.stdin` into my Node.js script. The problem I'm facing is that for each line read, I have to process it with an async function, and I want to wait for its callback before reading the next line:

```
readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
}).on('line', (input) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
    myAsyncFunction(input, (err, data) => { 
        /* Go on */ 
    });
});
```

I tried using `readline.pause()` and `resume()`, but it does not work. All lines but the last one are read without waiting for `resume()`, then after `resume()` the last one is read (I think it's just because the last line in my input is not terminated with a `\n`):

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
});

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    rl.pause(); // Pause after receiving a line
    console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        rl.resume(); // Resume after async operation finishes
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The issue is that `.pause()` will not necessarily prevent more `line` events from being emitted, as `stdin` is read in blocks. Even when paused, until the current block has been "emptied", more `line` events will occur. Perhaps you can stuff the lines into an [`async.queue`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) with a concurrency of one, if your goal is to limit the number of concurrent calls to `myAsyncFunction`.

Comment: @robertklep Good idea. I already use `async` in my project, but didn't know about its `queue`